# Access object in ModelChoiceField in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have a `ModelChoiceField` in which I use widget `RadioSelect`.

I iterate through choice options in my template but I can only get `choice.tag` and `choice.choice_label`. I will access all the fields in the specific object and not just the choice label.

I know I can use `label_from_instance` to change the `choice_label` but it's not enough to only have 1 field.

## Edit

Right now I iterate with `{% for choice in form.field %}{{ choice.tag }}{% endfor %}`. Choice only contains `tag` and `choice_label`. I want it to also contain `choice.object` or something so I can use `choice.object.id`, `choice.object.full_name`, `choice.object.gender` etc.

Comment: what is your problem?!!

Comment: Right now I iterate with `{% for choice in form.field %}{{ choice.tag }}{% endfor %}`. Choice only contains `tag` and `choice_label`. I want it to also contain `choice.object` or something so I can use `choice.object.id`, `choice.object.full_name`, `choice.object.gender` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use something like this:

```
{% for field in form.visible_fields %}{# loop over form fields #}
    {% if field.name == "choice_field_name" %}
        {% for choice in field.queryset %} {# loop over choices #}
            {# here you access to choice object #}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: `{{ form.choice_field_name.queryset }}` is empty/not existing. That's the problem.

Comment: create `ModelChoiceField` like this:
`choice_field_name = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=MyModel.objects.all())`

Comment: Okay. Now I have `choice_field_name = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=MyModel.objects.all(), widget=forms.RadioSelect())` but `{{ form.choice_field_name.queryset }}` is still empty

Comment: It should be `{% for choice in form.choice_field_name.field.queryset %}` :D

Comment: But how do I get my tag `<input type=radio" ...`

Comment: `<input value="{{choice.id}}" type="radio" name="my_name" />{{choice.description}}`

Comment: I'm having the same issue as this. I want to access other fields of the model but somehow it is returning empty. Is there any way to access other fields of the object from the template?